# Compose key doesn't work in Geany

Tags: geany, compose-key

(20.04.1 LTS)

I've set a compose key using the tweaks tool, and in most applications it works great.

However, in Geany, pressing that key makes the application window flash briefly, and nothing else happens. This happens no matter which key I assign in the tweaks tool (I've tried both alts, both controls, and capslock so far).

Is there a way to fix or work around this? Or do I need to switch to a new IDE?

Comment: What is a "compose" key?

Comment: @KevinBowen [It's a way of typing symbols that don't have a dedicated key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key)

Comment: @KevinBowen Enabled the compose key in tweaks, then tried to use it in various applications. In most places (LibreOffice, Firefox, terminal) it works as expected, letting me insert various special characters. In Geany, if I press the compose key, the window flashes and nothing else happens. It seems to be an issue with Wayland GDK that also affects dead keys; forcing the X11 backend fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same issue [reported here](https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/2105) and [also here](https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/2575). As jpralves says in the first thread:

> Solved by running geany with the following command: `GDK_BACKEND=x11 geany`
>
> It seems to be a problem with wayland gdk.

And this does indeed fix the issue! Compose key working fine again.